# RewriteRule without using the domain name

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently use a `RewriteRule` to direct all traffic to a `index.php` file which then decides which page to serve. The current rule works fine and looks like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

This means if I go to the following URL, the correct page will be displayed:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/20/0/0/0/0/0/0/0
```

My problem:

I'd like to be able to add the link `/teaching-and-training/20` to my page which should redirect to the above URL, i.e. `/main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/20/0/0/0/0/0/0/0`

I can get this to work if I use the following `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^teaching-and-training/([0-9]+)$
http://www.mydomain.com/main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/$1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0 [L]
```

but it does not work if I remove the `http://www.mydomain.com` part. I need to remove this part.

**EDIT:** By "does not work" I mean the redirection is successful, however the URL is changed to the ugly, long URL. I would like the URL to remain as `teaching-and-training/20`.

I suspect the problem is that `main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/$1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0` doesn't really exist (the `index.php` file is able to figure out which page this is), so my question is this:

Is there some way I can make `^teaching-and-training/([0-9]+)$` display `/main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/$1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0` by either using a little bit more `RewriteRule` magic, or by combining it with the `index.php` `RewriteRule`?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want `teaching-and-training/([0-9]+)` to display that long URL, then you should place the rule *first* (i.e. near the top of the file) and not use `[L]`. This way, `mod_write` will rewrite it once, and then *again* when it hits your normal rule. The `[L]` means "this rule is last, if it matches, run with what I've just rewritten you to" which is the opposite of what you wanted.

```
RewriteRule ^teaching-and-training/([0-9]+)$ /main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/$1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried those changes and it gives a 500 error. From the logs I can see the following: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters.

Comment: I've tried your updated rule and it works... however, it is changing the URL from /teaching-and-training/20 to the long, ugly URL. Is there a way to keep the URL as /teaching-and-training/20? Thanks

Comment: Ah I misunderstood what you wanted, sorry. Please see my revised answer.

Comment: Please don't apologise, I should have explained better. :) I have tried your suggestion but it gives a 404 error. This is my htaccess: RewriteRule ^teaching-and-training/([0-9]+)$ /main/index/1/basic/0/0/date/14/0/0/$1/0/0/0/0/0/0/0

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]

Comment: You probably need to tinker with it some more. Try making it `main/` instead of `/main`, etc. Difficult for me to see what the problem is from here, but it sounds like it's being re-written incorrectly (but we are getting somewhere nonetheless). You might also like to try `RewriteBase /` right after `RewriteEngine On`. `mod_rewrite` is a funny beast.